# Looking to replace a failed resistor when the color bands have burned away

Tags: resistors

I have a TwinStar International CFI-470-10 "electric fireplace" -- a quartz heater in a faux fireplace enclosure which is lit by an incandescent bulb and a pair of colored LEDs.  A while back the lights stopped working and of course it's out of warranty.  When I investigated I found this small board in the back of the unit:

[image: Top of board]

[image: Bottom of board]

The inbound side is from the dimmer and the outbound side goes to the LEDs.  I know normally it would be difficult to make a reasonable guess as to what the value would be but since it's a fairly simple circuit with a straightforward function I thought I'd give it a shot.

I did reach out to the manufacturer's website hoping for either a schematic or the value of the resistor but never got an answer.

**EDIT 1**

Adding pictures of the LED assembly and the dimmer.

[image: LED assembly]

[image: Dimmer]

[image: Capacitor]

Comment: That is a *very* failed resistor, wow. What's that connector connect to?

Comment: Welcome. It would really help if you provided a bit more detail, and showed all the elements. Including the "dimmer" and the number of LEDs.  What you have looks like a simple RC dropper to limit current flow from th AC mains to your load. Be careful as it doesn't provide isolation from the mains.

Comment: @Hearth the connector goes to the LEDs.

Comment: @colintd I added photos, please let me know what other details would help.

Comment: Resistors don't burn up like that normally. There must be a fault somewhere else in the circuit that made the resistor to burn up. There is no visible markings to determine what the value was any more. And if you replace the resistor with a new one, it will just burn up again if the problem that causes the resistor to burn is not fixed. And the resistor may need to be a special fusible resistor in order to burn up safely without igniting fire, so you must know what type of resistor is needed for replacement after the fault that burns up resistors is fixed.

Comment: Whatever happened has also completely vapourised one of the traces on the PCB as well. Note the long gap in the solder mask in the middle of the board in the last but one picture where it used to be.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, do you have a multimeter? If so, try measuring the resistor to see if it has actually failed open, or whether it has just destroyed the outside paint (still would need replacing, but if in tact the reading could give you it's value).

Comment: @TomCarpenter great call, I didn't see the blown out trace until you mentioned it.  I checked and the resistor has failed open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are the film capacitor has failed short (though that type tends to be self-healing) and it may well have taken out whatever it was connected to.

The value of the resistor is not too critical, it can be estimated from the capacitance marked on C1 and pick something that will dissipate a few hundred mW to perhaps half a watt. However it should be a flameproof/fusible type so it doesn't set (non-faux) fire to anything when this happens the next time.

As I said, I suspect C1 and probably whatever it's connected to (LEDs?) have been destroyed.

Maybe you could find something else to replace the whole mess with, especially if the LEDs were some kind of special self-flicker type.

---

The only remotely likely way that I can see that just the resistor would have gone is if there was some kind of electrical short such as from one end of the resistor to ground. That's unlikely to just randomly happen with the unit sitting there, unless the product was exceptionally badly built, but only you know the full history of the failure.

Comment: I particularly appreciate the gentle suggestion to "replace the whole mess" as ultimately that's really the best path to safety.  

After thinking about that for some time, I realized I could just rip out the entire LED assembly and replace it with one of those "flicker flame" light bulbs.  The result isn't quite the same but for a $5 solution I'll take it!